# Extension getting current open apps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to launch apps with my extension, but I need to check if it's already open, so I don't reopen it or open a new app window.

Is there anyway I can do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [chrome.windows.getAll](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-getAll) to list all windows of `app` type and [chrome.management.launchApp](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-launchApp) to launch an app if its window wasn't found.

**Required permissions** in manifest.json: `"tabs"`, `"management"`.

```js
function launchApp(id, callback) {
    chrome.windows.getAll({
        windowTypes: ['app'],
        populate: true
    }, function(windows) {
        if (windows.some(function(w) { return w.tabs[0].url.indexOf(id) > 0 })) {
            if (callback) {
                callback({state: 'already running'});
            }
            return;
        }
        chrome.management.launchApp(id, function() {
            if (callback) {
                callback({state: 'launched'});
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Usage:

```js
var appID = 'lkbbjdgfngikaledbinmnhkappgpnklb';
launchApp(appID, function(state) {
    console.log(state);
});
```

Comment: According to the windows.getAll API, "with 'app' and 'panel' window types limited to the extension's own windows". I need to check all apps :/

Comment: No, that quote is related to the default state when `windowTypes` is not specified.